# Error: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a main to create a AFN, a simple class and project structure in intelliJ, however I am having the error:

> Java HotSpot (TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported
>   for bootloader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended

[image]

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>saenyravalyris</groupId>
    <artifactId>saenyravalyris</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

Main.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException {

        Long linesNumber;
        int lineNumber = 0;
        ArrayList<String> states = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> entries = new ArrayList<>();
        String initialState = "";
        String finalState = "";

        try {
            FileReader leitor = new FileReader("config.txt");
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(leitor, 2 * 1024 * 1024);
            linesNumber = buffer.lines().count();

            String line = buffer.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                System.out.print(line + "\n");

                ArrayList<String> splitResults = new ArrayList<>();
                splitResults.addAll(Arrays.asList(line.split(" ")));

                if(lineNumber == 1) {
                    states.addAll(splitResults);
                } else if(lineNumber == 2) {
                    entries.addAll(splitResults);
                } else if(lineNumber == linesNumber - 1) {
                    initialState = line;
                } else if(lineNumber == linesNumber) {
                    finalState = line;
                } else {
                    String matrix[][] = new String[states.size()][entries.size()];
                    int matrixLine = 0;
                    int matrixColumn = 0;

                    for (matrixLine = 0; matrixLine <= entries.size(); matrixLine++) {
                        for (matrixColumn = 0; matrixColumn <= states.size(); matrixColumn++) {
                            matrix[matrixLine][matrixColumn] = line;
                        }
                    }

                    System.out.print(matrix);
                }

                line = buffer.readLine();

                lineNumber = lineNumber + 1;
                Thread.sleep(1000);

                System.out.print(states);
                System.out.print(entries);
                System.out.print(initialState);
                System.out.print(finalState);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.print(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I did some research but did not find a solution that worked and solved this problem. Would it be something with Intellij or my java version?

Comment: This warning is harmless, it does not affect the behavior of your program in any way.

Comment: Thank you, I will ignore it